# How to compile CGAL programs on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++, cgal

OS X El Capitan 10.11.2
Installed CGAL library via macports (version 2.3.4)

I have a file (/Users/Arseniy/Desktop/vec.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_2.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
int main()
{
  Point_2 points[5] = { Point_2(0,0), Point_2(10,0), Point_2(10,10), Point_2(6,5), Point_2(4,1) };
  Point_2 result[5];
  Point_2 *ptr = CGAL::convex_hull_2( points, points+5, result );
  std::cout <<  ptr - result << " points on the convex hull:" << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < ptr - result; i++){
    std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also i found headers of CGAL library (/usr/local/include/CGAL).

And when i tried to compile it via g++ in terminal (g++ -0 vec vec.cpp -lCGAL -I/usr/local/include/CGAL) I see the error:
"ld: library not found for -lCGAL
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

I'm pretty new to gcc. This problem may seem easy to you but I am here to learn.

Thank you for your attention and your help!

Comment: So, i replaced the file vec.cpp into (/usr/local/include/CGAL) the folder with h-files of CGAL library. And now gcc send me only the one error: vec.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 
      'CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h' file not found
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>   But this file actually exists.
         ^
1 error generated.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Pods isn't being included in the build.

Can you check the pods root path in xcode please? To do this, click "pods" > build settings > and where you see "PODS_ROOT" double click that, which show something like

**${SRCROOT}/../Pods**

If everything is fine, the issue will be pods isn't being installed, run pods install ( pod install) 
For further reference use this link 
http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/cocoapods-dependancy-management-for-xcode/139

Sorry If this Doesn't Solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the linker the path to the CGAL library using the -L option. You are also probably missing the -frounding-math flag.
CGAL recommends to use cmake.